Issues with installing ADDA packahe in Python conda Environment
I am having trouble installing the ADDA package. Although I have installed HoloPy, I'm still getting errors. Could you please help me with the installation process?
I installed HoloPy in myenv after activating myenv:
HoloPy runs on Python version 3.6.2. HoloPy is available on conda-forge, so you can install it within a shell, terminal, or command prompt:



conda install -c conda-forge holopy



Then I Clone the ADDA repository:



git clone https://github.com/adda-team/adda.git



In a terminal window, When I go to the directory ’adda/src’ and compile using one of three options given in the HoloPy tutorial:
make seq
or:
make
or:
make OpenCL
https://holopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/dda_tutorial.html#dda-tutorial
I am getting this error message: "'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.."
